# How do I use the OpenFileDialog class such that it opens on the Network area as default?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

How do I use the OpenFileDialog class (in C#, WPF etc.) such that it opens on the Network area as default?

This does not work:

```
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
  openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Network";
```

I also tried having "\" as an InitialDirectory and that did not work.

I also tried having "\\" as an InitialDirectory and that did not work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this should work:

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts);
```

[`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) returns the path corresponding to an [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) enumeration entry as a string.

`Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts` is defined as

> A file system directory that contains
>   the link objects that may exist in the
>   My Network Places virtual folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Customize Your Open File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx) from the Microsoft MSDN Magazine has a *lot* of information on the dialog. I haven't had chance to read it all, but this caught my eye:

> **A Custom Places Bar**
>   ...
>
> You'll need a REG_SZ entry if the name of the folder is an absolute or relative path. You need to use the folder-specific number if you want to target a special folder (see Figure 6 for a list). In this case, a REG_DWORD entry is needed.
>
> Figure 6
>
> Folder IDs
>
> ID    Folder
>   0   Desktop
>   2   Programs folder on Start menu
>   3   Control Panel
>   4   Printers
>   5   My Documents
>   6   Favorites
>   7   Startup folder on Start menu
>   8   Recent Files
>   9   Send To
>   10  Recycle Bin
>   12  Start menu
>   17  My Computer
>   18  My Network Places
>   20  Fonts

I've missed a whole load of stuff out (because it's a very long article), but it looks like you can set the ID value to 18 to get your network places. However, as @Nelson points out this might part looks like it's adding an entry to the bar, so double check it before using.  As I said before the post I've linked to contains a *lot* of information, so what you need may well be buried somewhere in it.

**Update:**

On Windows 7 PC's it doesn't work. eg:

```
OpenDialogPlaces o = new OpenDialogPlaces();
//o.Places.Add(18);
//o.Places.Add(5);
//o.Places.Add(6);
o.Init();
o.OpenDialog.ShowDialog();
o.Reset();
```

Still shows everything in the left-hand:

[image]

It did work in previous versions of Windows:

[image]

Another thing it appears Microsoft has changed the ComDlg32's location, I tried both places but no luck.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like that would add it to the bar (as a shortcut), but not actually start there?

Comment: @Nelson - As I said, I haven't had chance to double check everything on that page, but I thought it would be a useful starting point. I'll update the answer to reflect your doubt.